# Access to XMLHttpReuqest has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: spring, server, cors, openapi, web-development-server

So I have been developing a Web Application using Angular Spring and Maven. I configured everything locally and now I am trying to run it on my Ip4 address Wifi.
x.x.x.x is basically my ip4 address
This is the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://x.x.x.x:8080/api/v1/registration' from origin 'http://x.x.x.x:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

and this is my HTTP config:

```
  @Bean
  public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

    // Possibly...
    //  config.applyPermitDefaultValues();

    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://x.x.x.x:4200");
    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://x.x.x.x:8080");
    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return source;
  }
```

I also use OpenAPI for the backend and I use the following configuration:

```
    openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Adesso FreeSeek API v1
  description: F
  version: 0.0.1
servers:
  - url: http://x.x.x.x:8080
    description: Local Wifi Server
tags: ..
```

And for my controller, I have set the following:

```
@Service
@Getter
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://x.x.x.x:4200", allowCredentials = "true")
public class FreeseekApiDelegateImpl implements ApiApiDelegate { ..
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.